# Linearly independent vectors and Span

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say $F$ be a field $\mathbb{Z_2}$.

Can we say that a set of linearly independent vectors $S$ that span $\mathbb{R^4}$ will also span $F^4$?

I can see that $F^4 \subset \mathbb{R^4}$, because $F^4 = \{(0,0,0,0), (0,0,0,1), ... ,(1,1,1,1)\}$.

So if $S$ spans $\mathbb{R^4}$ is it okay to automatically assume that $S$ also spans $F^4$?

Comment: You're wrong. $\mathbf F_2$ is certainly not contained in $\mathbf R$, for at least one reason: $1+1=0$ in the former, whereas it is $2$ in the latter. More generally, finite fields are *not* subsets of $\mathbf R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider $S=\{(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$ a subset of $\textsf{F}^3$. If $\textsf{F}=\mathbb{R}$, then $S$ is linearly independent (check it). While, if $\textsf{F}=\mathbb{Z}_2$, then $S$ is linearly dependent :
$$(1,1,0)+(1,0,1)=(0,1,1)$$

Comment: Perfect. I knew something was off. Yes I agree with your insight. Thanks!